# hail and fire in Egypt

Tags: plagues-makkos

The *posuk* says, *''There was hail and fire flaming amid the hail''* [*Shemos* 9:24].

Does anyone know what day the hail and fire fell in Egypt? (i.e. Sunday, Monday or Tuesday etc.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70469/timeline-of-the-10-plagues-in-exodus

Comment: Why is this information important or useful?

Answer (score 1):

All of them. The Makkos each lasted for at least one full week (Shemos Rabbah 9:12). But I agree with the comments - I don't know why exactly this is a question here.