# How long did the plagues last?

Tags: bo, va-eira

From the beginning of the first plague with the Nile turning to blood up to the ninth plague of darkness, what is the time frame for the total length of time? I have not been able to find a definitive answer, I have heard it was one month or maybe one year. (I know that the ninth plague of darkness only lasted 3 days.)

Comment: some opinions cited here https://books.google.com/books?id=CiC2CpjUZa0C&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=%22each+plague+lasted+a%22&source=bl&ots=VB9oMX1C_u&sig=HuoBMBNhaxNKvYdOYrtyKFVpasI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcmrO-rOvRAhXH7YMKHQYBDXQQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22each%20plague%20lasted%20a%22&f=false http://www.nachumsegal.com/taking-closer-look-pesach-rabbi-dov-kramer-5774/

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36570/472

Comment: Plague of darkness was six days. three days of thick darkness and three day in which the Egyptians could not move. Rashi Bo 10:22 Thick darkness in which they did not see each other for those three days, and another three days of darkness twice as dark as this, so that no one rose from his place

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8466/603 -- see here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rashi (Shemot 7:25) writes that each plague lasted a week, and there were three weeks of admonition before each plague:

> וימלא: מנין שבעת ימים, שלא שב היאור לקדמותו, שהיתה המכה משמשת רביע חדש ושלשה חלקים היה מעיד ומתרה בהם:
>
> Seven full days passed: Heb. וַיְּמָּלֵא, literally, seven days were filled. Since the word וַיְּמָּלֵא is singular, Rashi explains: The number of seven days that the Nile did not return to its original state [was filled], for the plague would be in effect for a quarter of a month, and for three quarters [of the month], he [Moses] would exhort and warn them. — [from Tanchuma, Va’era 13, Exod. Rabbah 9:12, as explained by Mizrachi and Gur Aryeh].
> Copied from chabad.org