# One plague per month?

Tags: plagues-makkos, va-eira

I just heard in a shiur that each plague happened in a different month, meaning that the 10 Makot lasted a full year. Does anyone have any sources for this?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Eduyot.2.10

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79632/603

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8438/603

Comment: Thanks to both of you