# Did Noach live 950 years or 951 years

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach, contradiction

Did Noach live 950 years or 951 years?

At the begining of the flood Noach was 600 years old [Bereishis 7,6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0107.htm#6):

> ונח בן שש מאות שנה והמבול היה מים על הארץ

The flood lasted 1 year as Rashi says [Bereishis 8,14](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8172/showrashi/true#v14):

> משפט דור המבול שנה תמימה היה

This means Noach was 601 at the end of the flood. It then says Noach live 350 years **after the flood** in [Bereishis 9,28](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0109.htm#28):

> ויחי נח אחר המבול שלש מאות שנה וחמשים שנה

This adds up to 951 years. Yet it says That Noach lived 950 years in Berishis 9,29:

> ויהיו כל ימי נח תשע מאות שנה וחמשים שנה וימת

The Torah is perfect so whats the deeper meaning?

Comment: The numbers are rounded.  He most likely didn't die on his birthday so it depends how you count the partial years.

Comment: Doesn't Rashi address this at length regarding Shem's age at the flood?

Comment: @heshy i won't accept such an answer as It says hNoach was a Tzadik and Tzadikim die comleting their years As its written "es Mispar Yomecho amalei" and also one would need a proof.that the years were incomplete

Comment: @user15464 There have been plenty of Tzaddikim throughout time who haven't died on their birthdays.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sounds like that would be an answer. Which Rashi are you referring to? I just skimmed through the Rashi on Sefaria, and couldn't find what you're referring to (specifically, I don't see anything on 11:10-11).

Comment: @user15464 You have it backwards.  Most people don't die on their birthday. 
 When somebody does, you need a proof for that, as in בן מאה ועשרים שנה אנכי היום.  And anyway, he wasn't born on both the 17th of (Cheshvan|Iyar) and (Rosh Hashana|Rosh Chodesh Nisan), so however you handle it, either the 600 or 601 years are incomplete.

Comment: With 3 different systems of counting months in this parsha (see Rashi), rounded years is the #1 thing that you're worried about?

Comment: If I recall correctly I have seen somewhere that the year of the flood is not counted.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8438/

Comment: see the sources in the answer given here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8466/603 -- the footnote in Likkutei Sichot there (it is in hebrew) explains that even a partial year can be considered a whole year when counting years of people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying from [YEZ’s answer to the related question of whether Moshe was 120 or 121](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36593/):

> The Da'as Zkeinim (and the Chizkuni) at the beginning of Parshas Noach
>   addresses this issue in a different context - The posuk says תמים by
>   Noach, and the Midrash says (Bereishis Rabba 30:8) that anyone
>   described as such lived to an age the which is the multiple of 7 (full
>   שבוע).  Noach's 950 do not add (or divide) up.  He answers that he
>   lived this amount from the time which the Torah described him as תמים,
>   the 350 years after the Mabul.  However, there is an extra year, the
>   year of the Mabul itself, which came after he was described as תמים! 
>   Says the Da'as Zkeinim:
>
> > סלק שנת המבול שאינה נחשבת לפי שנשתנו בה סדרי בראשית
> >
> > Remove the year of the Mabul, which is not counted because the order of Creation was altered
>
> So a year in which the laws of nature are suspended does not count.
>
> This answers a very similar question to your own:
>
> the Torah says that Noach was 600 at the start of the flood
>   ([Bereishis 7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0107.htm):6), and that he lived 350 years after the flood
>   ([Bereishis 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0109.htm):28), and that he lived a total of 950 years
>   (Bereishis 9:29).  So what happened to the year of the flood?  It
>   isn't counted, as above.

Comment: I don’t feel right gaining XP off an answer that’s just copy-pasting from someone else’s hard work, so I’ve marked this community wiki.

Comment: Is searching on this site and finding an answer fundamentally different from searching on another site and finding an answer?