# Sotah saving herself by disqualifying the mincha

Tags: korban, kavana-intent, tractate-sotah, sotah-secluded-woman, rav-yosef-engel

The gemara in [Zevachim 47a](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.47a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) quotes the opinion of Rabbi Elazar Bar Rabbi Yose who holds that not only the kohen who is being makrev a korban can disqualify, but even the owner can disqualify.  Upon this opinion we can come to a case where the Sotah herself will have in mind while the kohen is preparing the mincha for a non accepted time, and will make the korban mincha into piggul. Then the water won't be valid to test the woman since the korban wasnt accepted since it was turned piggul, and no one but her will know that she has no risk even though she is guilty. So how can we confidently say the sotah test always works if there is a loophole for the Sotah to be guilty and survive?

This question was asked by Rav Yosef Engel and he gave 80 answers in his Gevuros Shimonim. I beileve one of his answers is that this shitta of Rabbi Elazar Bar Rabbi Yose only applies by Kodsehi Kalim,but not by Kodesh Kodoshim. Does anyone know his other answers? (I do not own his sefer)

I also wanted to know if one of his answers states that although there is a loophole, we can still say that a miracle will occur and if she is guilty she would still be killed even though the korban mincha was invalid.

Comment: Is this it? http://hebrewbooks.org/22491

Comment: yes that looks like it , I never got a chance to read it yet.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2603/21

Comment: Isn't it the husband who is the owner of the sacrifice? Why can the sota make it piggul?

Comment: @ba the woman does the waving since she's seemingly the Baalim. I don't know why the husband would be the Baalim here.

Comment: DoubleAA - The husband sponsors it. The achronim discuss who is considrere the baalim.

Comment: @DoubleAA I browsed through the book and apparently what I thought is [answer 15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22491&st=&pgnum=10)

Comment: @chortkov he can sponsor it. Must he? Anyone can pay for anyone else's offerings generally

Comment: @וְהֵבִיא אֶת קָרְבָּנָהּ עָלֶיהָDoubleAA:  - refers to the husband. See also  כסף משנה על הרמב"ם בפ"ג מסוטה הי"ב; there is a discussion whether specifically this Korbon or whether the husband must fund any korbon a woman must bring...

Comment: According to answer #8 (and #9?) there's an exception for sotah.

Comment: I skimmed it over and don't see any answers suggesting she would die even if the mincha was invalidated.

Comment: Isn't piggul punished by kares and thus the sotah would still be punished with death even if this worked to stop the sotah water from killing her?

Answer (score 2):

Reb Sruly Bornstein beautifully presents a nice selection of the Gevuros Shemonim's answers:

Listen to the Reid Bite "בענין הספר ״גבורות שמונים״" from Sotah 19 by Sruly Bornstein on the Lakewood Daf Yomi app! https://app.lakewooddafyomi.com/browse/listen?type=other&id=257470002

Comment: Could you summarize what R' Bornstein says?