# Shelosha Vetish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 193 chapters in [the תשובות](http://hebrewbooks.org/1746) of [רב יעקב ווייל](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Weil).

Answer (score 2):

> The first transport, carrying 1030 Jews from Rome, reached Auschwitz on October 23, 1944. Aboard were 296 children and juveniles under age 17. One hundred ninety-three of the children were under 10 years old....

— [*Anatomy of the Auschwitz Death Camp*](http://books.google.com/books?id=mub823JQrdUC), page 416.

Answer (score 1):

From the time Yaakov Avinu died till we left Mitzrayim and received the Torah was 193 years.

Yaakov came to Mitzrayim when he was 130 years old and passed away 17 years later at the age of 147.

210 years in Mitzrayim - 17 years that Yaakov lived in Mitzrayim = 193

Answer (score 0):

There were 193 years from "*lech l'cha*" (if [it was when *Avram* was 75](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2496)) until [*Yosef* was sold](http://web.archive.org/web/20090130120032/http://www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html).