# Meya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

[image: ""]

### Who knows one hundred?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point in the future, subject to [holiday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukkot) and [user activity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/shivim-mi-yodeya/2403#2403) delay, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, 100, here we go!

1. The Heichal of the second Beish Hamikdash was 100 amos tall. -msh210
2. ..and 100 amos long.
3. ..and 100 amos wide.
4. Brochos to say each day -JeremyR
5. 100 times ש״ם is written in Tehillim. -Yahu
6. 100 amos<sup>2</sup> where the Kohanim walked on top of the exterior altar. -msh210
7. 100 children of Kayin. -Gershon Gold
8. 100 people that Elish fed miraculously. -msh210
9. 100 cc's in the Chazon Ish's K'beitzah -msh210
10. Shem was 100 years old when his son Arpachshad was born. -msh210
11. 100 prophets that OVadya hid from Izevel. -msh210
12. 100 is the number used for large examples in Rabbinic literature. -msh210
13. 100 amos that water must travel underground before it's considered a spring when it comes back up. -msh210
14. 100 amos tall was Adam. -msh210
15. 100 amos around a grave that there might still be body parts. -msh210
16. 100 amos is how far the carob tree moved. -msh210
17. 100 זוז in a woman's second marriage kesubah. -Gershon Gold
18. 100 walk-amos is the duration of a light sleep. -Isaac Moses
19. 100 Shofar blasts on Rosh Hashana. -Isaac Moses
20. 100 species of impure birds in the east. -Isaac Moses
21. 100 is how much Yaakov paid for real-estate near Sh'chem. -msh210
22. 100 years will still be young at death says Yechezkel HaNavi. -msh210
23. 100 years old when Sarah still looked like 20. -msh210
24. 100 zuz wants another 100 zuz. -Isaac Moses
25. 100 silver that a מוציא שם רע pays. -Yahu
26. 100 times that "שמים" is written in Torah. -Yahu
27. Torah learning is 100 times more valuable in difficult circumstances. -Isaac Moses
28. 100 times that you must have said Mashiv Haruach, before you can assume that you say the right one without thinking. -ArghMo
29. Heter 100 Rabbis. -ArghMo
30. 100 silver sockets for the Mishkan. -YDK
31. 100 answers for the missing miracle question. -Isaac Moses
    Meah Shearim. -Yahu
32. The cross-sectional area of the Mishkan (viewed from the East or West) was 100 square cubits (10x10). -Isaac Moses
33. 100 times the chullin must outnumber the terumah to be able to use the mixture. -Dave
34. 100 years old was Avraham when Yitzchak was born. -jutky
35. 100 Rabbis from R' Moshe Feinstein's home town. -Alex
36. 100 amos was the length of the Mishkan's courtyard. -Dave
37. 100 zuz in a maneh. -Shalom
38. 100 times the word בנימן is in Tanach. -Shalom
39. 100 times the word האחד is in Tanach. -Shalom
40. 100 reviews which is incomparable to 101 reviews (Chagiga 9b) -HodofHod because..
41. 100 reviews is what was common in Talmudic times (brought in Tanya Ch. 15) -HodofHod
42. 100 zuz is the value of virginity at the time of marriage.
43. 100 clusters of raisins that Tziva brought to Dovid. (2 Shmuel 16) -HodofHod
44. 100 summer fruits that Tziva brought to Dovid. (ibid.) -HodofHod
45. "The city that went forth a thousand shall have a hundred left" (Amos 5:3) -HodofHod
46. "And five of you shall chase a hundred, and a hundred of you shall chase ten thousand". (Vayikra 26:8). -HodofHod
47. בן מאה שנים כאילו עבר ובטל מן העולם. -Dave
48. אַרְתַּחְשַׁסְתְּא guaranteed Ezra 100 talents of silver.
49. ..and 100 measures of wheat.
50. ..and 100 baths of wine.
51. ..and 100 baths of oil. (Ezra 7:22) -HodofHod
52. "A rebuke entereth deeper into a man of understanding than a hundred stripes into a fool." (Mishlei 17:10) -HodofHod
53. 100 amos was the length of King Solomon's house. (1 Kings 7:2) -HodofHod
54. 100 sheep that King Solomon's court went through, *a day*! (1 Kings 5:3) -HodofHod
55. 100 bullocks that were sacrifice when the 2nd Beis Hamikdash was completed. (Ezra 6:16) -HodofHod
56. 100 talents of silver the Ammon gave to King יוֹתָם.  (Chronicles 1 27:5) -HodofHod
57. 100 chariots that Dovid reserved from what he took from הֲדַדְעֶזֶר מֶלֶךְ-צוֹבָה . (Chronicles 1 18:4) -HodofHod
58. פַרְעֹה נְכֹה fined Israel 100 talents of silver during the reign of יְהוֹאָחָז. (Kings 2 23:33) -HodofHod

    *Gematria of:*
59. "לכן" -msh210
60. "מדה במדה" -msh210
61. "מדון" -msh210
62. "לך לך" -Gershon Gold
63. "מודים" -Gershon Gold
64. "המלכה" -Gershon Gold
65. "כף" -Gershon Gold
66. "פך" -Gershon Gold
67. "על"
68. "סם"
69. "ימים"
70. "כלים"
71. "בן חיל"
72. "יהועדה"
73. "ימלך"
74. "סכך"
75. "מס"
76. "ממך"
77. "מיכל"
78. "מלכי"
79. "סלי"
80. "מכם"
81. "עודך"
82. "המימה"
83. "מימי"
84. "נלך"
85. "ילין"
86. "טמאים"
87. "יגאלנו"
88. "ובחסדך"
89. "ויחלמו"
90. "גביעיה"
91. "ייסך"
92. "מני"
93. "בלחמך"
94. "ליני"
95. "כלכל"
96. "חצב"
97. "וילדים"
98. "יפי"
99. "בכוכבים"
100. Answers in this answer.

(Ok, I know the gematrias got a *little* out there, but you try coming up with 50 other references for 100!)

Comment: If you know another one that's not on the list, by all means please remove on of the gematrias and replace it!

Answer (score 11):

There's a target of saying 100 blessings every day.

[One-Hundred Brochos a Day and Keep the Doctor away and Bring Moshiach !](http://www.avakesh.com/2010/07/a-hundred-brochos-a-day.html)

Comment: Hello Jeremy, and welcome to mi.yodeya! Thank you for your on-target answer. If you have any more suggestions, feel free to add them here!

Answer (score 10):

One hundred walk-amot is the duration of a light sleep, according to Rami bar Yechezkel ([Sukka 26a](http://www.vbm-torah.org/talmud4/10.htm)).

---

We blow the shofar [100 times](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/618,2090388/How-many-shofar-blasts-do-we-hear-on-Rosh-Hashanah.html) on Rosh Hashana.

---

According to Isi ben Yehudah, "There are 100 species of Tamei birds in the east, they are all species of 'Ayah.'" ([Chulin 63a](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/chulin/points/ch-ps-063.htm))

Comment: The first answer is especially apt, and is mentioned by the Mishnah Brurah in 639:11.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17733

Answer (score 8):

In *[Sefer Ner Lemeah](http://ohr.edu/yhiy/article.php/1299)* R' Yerachmiel Zeltzer collected 100 answers (IY"H by us) to the following question:

> In the Chanuka story, given that the oil would naturally have lasted for one day, wasn't only the continued burning on the second through seventh days miraculous, and shouldn't we therefore only celebrate for seven days?

Answer (score 8):

100 silver sockets for the mishkan:

40 on the north

40 on the south

16 on the west

4 under the paroches

(Parashas Trumah 26:19-25)

Answer (score 7):

One HUNdred are the ZUZ in A man-EH.

(Fits the beat.)

The Gemara points out the Hebrew word for widow, "almanah", sounds a lot like the "maneh" she receives for her ketubah.

---

Gen. 42:13

> ויאמרו, שנים עשר עבדיך אחים אנחנו בני איש-אחד--בארץ כנען; והנה **הקטן** את-אבינו היום, ו**האחד** איננו

The words בנימן and האחד appear 100 times (each) in Tanach.

Comment: So 100 are the zuz in anlmana's kesubh!

Comment: And 100 are the additional zuz in a besula's kesubah

Answer (score 7):

If terumah fell into chullin, the mixture is prohibited as terumah unless the chullin is 100 times the amount of terumah (in which case the terumah is nullified). -- Terumos 4:7

Answer (score 6):

Heter Me'ah Rabbanim - If a woman refuses to accept a Get, an allowance from 100 rabbis may allow her husband to remarry anyway.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heter_meah_rabbanim

Comment: "One HUNdred are the RABBIS for POLyGAMy."  Fits the beat.

Comment: But hm, nah I don't see it going over well for Uncle Moishy.

Comment: Why not "poLYgaMY"?

Comment: Woops sorry you're right.  I'm not such an expert on polygamy. :)

Answer (score 6):

100 is the price (in קשיטה)‎ יעקב bought land near שכם for (Genesis 33:19).

Answer (score 5):

לא דומה הלומד 101 פעמים ללומד 100 פעמים

it was the age of Avraham when Itshak was born.

Answer (score 5):

בן מאה שנים כאילו עבר ובטל מן העולם

Answer (score 5):

The cross-sectional area of the [Mishkan](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=2077) (viewed from the East or West) was 100 square cubits (10x10).

Comment: Hence, too, the square cubitage of the _paroches_ was 100 (_Rashi_, _Sh'mos_ 26:32).

Answer (score 5):

Meyah Shearim is where I would like to be right now (at a Simchas Beis HaSho'eivah!)

Comment: Why it's called Mea Shearim: It says that Yitzchak sowed the land and got 100 times the amount (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mea_Shearim)

Comment: Right "100-fold."  Many people think there's something about a hundred gates, different use of the word "shaar."

Answer (score 5):

Difficult circumstances increase the value of Torah learning by at least 100x.

> אם למדת תורה
>   בשעת הריוח אל תשב לך בשעת הדחק לפי שטוב לו
>   לאדם דבר אחד בצער ממאה בריוח

([Avot D'Rabi Natan](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=38247&st=%u05de%u05d0%u05d4))

Comment: That's 20 so far, by my count ...

Answer (score 5):

[100 silver of the מוציא שם רע.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20137&hilite=7a9059e6-f20e-4b24-b473-db49facaa02f&st=%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8+%D7%9B%D7%93&pgnum=88)

Comment: =400 zuz, double that of similar offenses (ones umefateh).

Comment: Oh plus lashes.

Answer (score 4):

The courtyard of the Mishkan was 100 amos in length.

Answer (score 4):

It was said by a play on words that R' Moshe Feinstein's native city, Starobin, had "one hundred rabbis" (in Russian, "sta rabin") - in other words, one hundred laymen (baalei batim) who were fully knowledgeable enough that they could have served as community rabbis elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

100 zuz is how much more money a person wants when he already has 100 zuz.

> One who has 100 wants 200.

-- [Kohelet Raba 3:10](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol25/v25n433.shtml#20)

Answer (score 4):

In the second בית המקדש, the היכל building (including the אולם) was 100 אמות tall by 100 אמות long by (at its widest point) 100 אמות wide. (Source: *mishnayos Midos*.)

Comment: Yes, that counts as three facts. For 70, we counted each Nasi's gift separately.

Answer (score 4):

[A paper](http://homepages.nyu.edu/~dys216/papers/RJJ%20Copepods%20-%20Long%20Version%202.0.htm#_ftn34), a different version of which was apparently published in the J. Hal. Contemp. Soc., quotes the Tzemach Tzedek (Lubavitch, not Nikolsburg) as saying that 100 *amos* (cubits) is the distance water must travel underground before it comes up again to be considered a spring.

Answer (score 3):

[100 times "שמים" is written in the תורה.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20137&hilite=7a9059e6-f20e-4b24-b473-db49facaa02f&st=%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8+%D7%9B%D7%93&pgnum=88)

Answer (score 3):

[100 times ש״ם is written in Tehillim.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=20578&st=%u05E7%20%u05E4%u05E2%u05DE%u05D9%u05DD)

Comment: האמנם? It appears over 100 times just in the first 20 chapters of Tehillim. Maybe the Megaleh Amukos means that the word שם, in all of its conjugations, appears 100 times?

Comment: Alex, You are right! I checked it out in the original source.

Answer (score 3):

100 is how old Sara was (in years) when she was like a twenty-year-old for beauty (or sinlessness, depending on your version of the Midrash Raba).

Comment: Rashi, Parashas Breishis 5:32, quotes a midrash explaining that Noach didn't have children until 500 so they wouldn't be a bar onshin when the mabul came at 600.  This idea is based on the pasuk you brought below- at 100 he will die.

Comment: I think this is about #30...

Answer (score 3):

100 is how old (in years) one will die who will be said to have died young (Isaiah 65:20).

Answer (score 3):

Lech Lcha = 100

Modim = 100

Hamalka = 100

Kaf = 100

Pach = 100

Also a Kesuba for a previously married woman is 100 Zuz.

Comment: The "lech l'cha" one is especially meaningful because of the midrash that Hashem was hinting to the fact that Avraham would have a son at 100: http://tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/lechlecha.html

Comment: And if we're counting random g'matriyaos, with nothing special about them, then there are bunch more: על,‎ ההנהלה,‎ היפה,‎ etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

100 is [apparently](http://www.moreshet.net/oldsite/mishna/20-2-00/sunday.htm) the distance (in *amos* (cubits)) around a grave where one might assume he will find a piece of a corpse in the ground.

Answer (score 3):

[Some blogger](http://yeranenyaakov.blogspot.com/2005/11/standing-tall.html) quotes the Ben Ish Chay as saying that Adam was 100 *amos* (cubits) tall — but I have no other source for that, myself.

Comment: Bava Basra 75a (R' Meir, who says that 200 amos is "twice the height of Adam"); Bamidbar Rabbah 13:12 (R' Yehudah).

Answer (score 3):

100 was *Shem*'s age (in years) when his son *Arpachshad* was born ([*B'reshis* 11:10](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0111)).

Comment: This is about #50 ...

Answer (score 2):

What to do if you're not sure if you remembered to say Mashiv Haruach U'morid Ha'geshem in sh'moneh esrei?

If you've already said it **100** times, (some say only 90), we assume that you remembered to say it and you do not repeat sh'moneh esrei.

Comment: And some say it takes 101, based on this:  http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/3027/meya-mi-yodeya/3031#3031.  There's also those who argue that it takes 90 days of actual real-use habituation, one long chant may not cut it.

Comment: Woops 30 days of habituation (over which you'll pray 90+ times)

Answer (score 2):

100 is the distance (in *amos* (cubits)) a carob tree moved, in a famous story recorded in *Bavli*, *Bava M'tzia* 59b.

Comment: I think this is about #40.

Answer (score 2):

100 is the number of prophets *Ovadya* hid from *Izevel* ([*M'lachim* I 18:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T09a18)).

Answer (score 2):

The Medrash Rabba in Parshas Mishpatim mentions that Kayin had 100 children.

Answer (score 1):

$100 is the threshold value a Rabbi of mine suggested for determining whether a new garment deserves a ["Shehecheyanu"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shehecheyanu).

(Interestingly, he suggested the same threshold over many years, apparently not taking inflation into consideration. Perhaps the psychological value of that round number retains significance across inflation.)

Answer (score 1):

[100 is the number of answers Rabbi Yerachmiel Zeltser has collected to the question "Why do we call the 6th of Sivan *z'man matan torasenu* when the 7th was?".](http://www.torah.org/learning/hamaayan/5759/shavuos.html)

Answer (score 1):

100 is the number of people *Elisha* fed with a small amount of food ([*M'lachim* II 4:43](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T09b04)). (I haven't checked the commentaries, so it could be that this is an example of [the hyperbole mentioned above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/meya-mi-yodeya/3287#3287), but I doubt it. Note that [Rabbi Aron Tendler](http://www.torah.org/learning/parsha/hsummary/tazria.html) seems to say it really means 100.)

Comment: Also the Gemara seems to assume that it's literal, because it uses this to calculate that Elisha had 2200 full-time students (Kesubos 106a).

Answer (score 1):

100 cc is a *k'betza* according to [the Chazon Ish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Yeshaya_Karelitz), [IINM](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IINM). (As always, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).)

Answer (score 1):

The area, on top of the exterior altar, where the *kohanim* would walk was 26²−24²=100 square *amos* (cubits). Source: *mishnayos Midos* chapter 3.

Answer (score 1):

100 is the *gimatriya* of לכן and of מדה במדה. Source: *Baal Haturim*, start of *Pin'chas*.

Answer (score 0):

100 is a number used as an example of a very large number in rabbinic Hebrew, as in [Rashi to *D'varim* 15:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9979/showrashi/true#v1510) and as in "דוחה מאה תוכחות".‎

Comment: We find it used in Biblical Hebrew too - in Eccles. 6:3, "אם יוליד איש מאה".

Comment: @Alex: See also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/3027/meya-mi-yodeya/3292#3292

Answer (score 0):

100 is the *g'matriya* of "מדון" (Rashi, [Sanhedrin 7a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3623&size=1)).

Answer (score 0):

Centigrade version of [an answer to another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6520).