# Chamisha Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Beis Yosef ([Orach Chaim 46](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&pgnum=97)) calculates that on a typical day one would recite 105 blessings (five more than the [statutory minimum](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/meya-mi-yodeya/3041#3041)).

Answer (score 3):

Avraham live 105 years after the Bris Ben haBesarim.

Answer (score 3):

[The Chofetz Chaim's obit](http://www.beyondbt.com/2006/11/03/the-chofetz-chaims-obituary/)- aged 105

Comment: Interesting! Because in fact he lived to be only 94, as far as I know (he was born in 5599/1839).

Comment: Yeah, but 105 makes a better headline!  I'm not sure where the lines got crossed.

Answer (score 2):

The age of Shes when he begat Enosh.

Answer (score 2):

105 is the number of the last *daf* in *Eruvin*.

Answer (score 0):

105 are the verses in [Micha](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t18.htm).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​