# Shneim Asar Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twelve?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The waters of the *mabul* were at least 212 degrees Fahrenheit. Source: *Rav Chisda*, [*Z'vachim* 113:2](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4377&size=1).

Comment: But if they were "15 cubits above the highest mountains," wouldn't the temperature have been lower? The boiling point of water goes down by about 1 degree for every 500 feet of elevation.

Comment: I had thought of that. But presumably all the water was boiling, not only the top part of it. 212 is still not exact: presumably the weight of the top water would pressurize the bottom water enough to raise its boiling point, and anyway I don't know what the boiling point a very tall mass of water is (considering the varying pressure). Also I didn't take solution/suspension, which changes the boiling point (albeit slightly, considering how much water there was), into account. 212 is the best I could do. Any physicists?

Comment: However Noach measured temperature in Celsius?

Comment: Checkmark for the interesting discussion, not for the inherently Jewish-212-ness of the fact.

Answer (score -2):

צלפחד   =   212