# Gematria Methods - Levels of Importance

Tags: gematria-numerology

Does anyone know of a "priority list" for gematria significance? In other words, aside from the standard absolute value, which method would have the next level of importance/significance (i.e., Mispar Katan, Mispar Katan Mispari, AtBash, AlBam, and so on and so forth). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to follow the reply given by Rabbi Michael Tzadok at the following link:
[Seeking examples of various gematria methods](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28118/seeking-examples-of-various-gematria-methods?rq=1)
where he speaks of "kavanot", in which case the question of "grading" the importance of one valuation over another becomes ***a moot point***, if each gematria can attribute a unique aspect to the finding.

Comment: Adding this for resource sake: https://www.torahcalc.com/info/gematria/